# Compare types of generic type objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, compare

[Pythons documentation say](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#type):

> For example, the following two statements create identical type objects:

```
>>> class X:
...     a = 1
...
>>> X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))
```

I tested the statement with the following [code](http://ideone.com/rhWfMV):

```
class X:
    a = 1

foo = X()   

X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))
Y = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))

bar = X()
bar2 = X()
foobar = Y()

print( type(foo) is type(bar) ) # False

print( type(bar) is type(bar2) ) # True

print( type(bar) is type(foobar) ) # False
```

As you can see, objects of these classes are not equal. Is there any other possible comparison to evaluate these *identical* classes to True?

Comment: They create equivalent type objects, though different ones. If you use twice the same method, they will also be different when compared with `is`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the classes aren't identical. They are seperate classes that behave the same (at the moment!).

If you add a method or property to one of the classes, is it supposed to return False then? The fact is, the classes are seperate objects that reside at seperate memory locations, which is why `is` returns False.